# ScaleTransition anmation not giving smooth animation

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-desktop

I am working on flutter application. I want to to perform scale animation to Card widget and i am using ScaleTransition widget for that purpose. The animation is working but it is not smooth. All the descendent widget of Card widget (wgich are wrapped inside it) are something like shaking or slightly moving along with scale animation.
Here are the screenshots of my code.
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOHZT.png) [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAiri.png) [singleCard is the Card widget to show content inside]

Can anyone tell me what's wrong there and what can be right solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing non smooth animations, make sure that you are profiling performance with an app built in profile mode. The default Flutter build creates an app in debug mode, which is not indicative of release performance. For information, see Flutter’s build modes.

To run in profile mode use:

```
flutter run --profile
```

More on this topic:

- [Performance best practices](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices)
- [Flutter performance profiling](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/ui-performance)

Comment: Still same result.

Comment: can you add your animated widget code to your question?